# the icon on PE file doen`t change

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, portable-executable

I'm trying to change the icon of EXE file (path to EXE file is writing from console) by absolute path to image (.ico). Tried this code but nothing changed. Have anybody some ideas how to change the icon? (It`s now taking icon from one EXE and replace to another. Just change the icon of EXE file which path was written before)

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(stringEXE, GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE icon = CreateFile(stringICO, GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD size = GetFileSize(file, NULL);
DWORD sizeICO = GetFileSize(icon, NULL);
DWORD bytesReadFile, bytesReadIco;
PVOID pointer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
PVOID pIco = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeICO, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
ReadFile(icon, pIco, sizeICO, &bytesReadIco, NULL);
ReadFile(file, pointer, size, &bytesReadFile, NULL);
CloseHandle(file);
CloseHandle(icon);
HANDLE image = BeginUpdateResource(stringEXE, FALSE); // reading current exe
    if (image != NULL) { // if success
        if (UpdateResource(image, RT_ICON, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPVOID)pIco, bytesReadIco)) { // if updated
            std::cout << "Icon has been changed successfully!" << std::endl;
            EndUpdateResource(image,FALSE); // then lock it
        }
    }
```

Reference is from Microsoft Documentation about updating resources (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources)

Comment: Checking the results of all your function calls would be a good place to start

Comment: Windows (explorer) caches icons for executables. Have you tried restarting.

Comment: @RichardCritten restart didn`t help. same icon

Comment: Next test, create a shortcut to the modified exe and click change icon (on the shortcut) :- (a) is your updated icon in the list of available icons and (b) is it the first in the list ?

Comment: @RichardCritten i don't see my icon in the list of available icons

Comment: Then @AlanBirtles comment is most appropriate add full error checking to the code.

Comment: [The format of icon resources](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120720-00/?p=7083).

Comment: As the blog @IInspectable attached said, you need to find the real ICON ID which explorer use to show and then replace it with another.